# Advanced multiple photo upload script

Tags: upload, photo

I am looking for advanced multiple photo uploading script for ASP.Net Ex: www.flickr.com multiple uploader.I request you all please help me to find custom or already developed uploading script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a free solution but will do everything you need: http://i-load.radactive.com/

Good luck with your project!